# how to do image processing through bluemix

Tags: image-processing, ibm-cloud

I'm a starter of IBM Bluemix and i don't know how to use image processing tools. Please help me out with this. and also please tell me how to load the images into bluemix image processing tool.

Answer (score 3):

Have a check on `Alchemy API` of IBM Bluemix.

**AlchemyAPI** offers a set of three services that enable businesses and developers to build cognitive applications that understand the content and context within text and images. For instance, using [AlchemyAPI](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/alchemyapi), developers can perform tasks such as extracting the people, places, companies, and other entities mentioned in a news article or analyze an image to understand the contents of the photo.

- **AlchemyLanguage**

AlchemyLanguage is a collection of 12 APIs that offer text analysis through natural language processing. The AlchemyLanguage APIs can process text and help you to understand its sentiment, keywords, entities, high-level concepts and more.

- **AlchemyVision**

AlchemyVision understands and analyzes complex visual scenes without needing textual clues. Developers can use this API to do tasks like image recognition, scene recognition, and understanding the objects within images.

- **AlchemyData**

AlchemyData provides news and blog content enriched with natural language processing to allow for highly targeted search and trend analysis. Now you can query the world's news sources and blogs like a database.

An example screenshot of how it looks-

[image: screenshot]

They have a great tutorial [here](http://blog.alchemyapi.com/getting-started-with-alchemyapi-on-bluemix) on how to Get started - Step 1.

If you are looking for image processing using Python, here is a great [tutorial](http://www.alchemyapi.com/developers/getting-started-guide/using-alchemyapi-with-python) with simplistic steps on how to kick off.

More examples or references-

- [Bluemix - Tutorials Videos](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/bluemix/quick-start-bluemix.html)
- [Analyze notes with the AlchemyAPI service on IBM Bluemix](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/cc-analyze-notes-alchemyapi-trs-bluemix/)
- [Getting started with the Visual Recognition service](https://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/doc/visual-recognition/)
- [Real Time Analysis of Images Posted on Twitter Using Bluemix](http://fatih-bulut.blogspot.in/2015/04/real-time-analysis-of-images-posted-on.html)
- [Editors' picks: Top 15 Bluemix tutorials](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-bestoflbluemix2014/)

Comment: And BTW, if you are going for the Bluemix hackathon this weekend, All the best! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to use runtimes, you could use imagemagick libraries, recently added on Cloud Foundry. The binaries should be on this path
/var/vcap/packages/imagemagick/bin

Otherwise you can refer to the chosen buildpack specific options: for example with the php one you could use GD library, installing through composer utility

```
{ "require": { "ext-gd": "*" } }
```

Another opportunity could be to use a docker container instead of a runtime, which allows you to keep the scalability opportunities of Bluemix but giving you wider configuration options.

Generally speaking it depends a lot from the technology you would like to use (java/php/python etc...)